# How to not auto start lightdm at boot

Tags: linux, opensuse, window-manager

I am working on the project which major on console based on opensuse. But some time need to run some gui application. I installed the lightdm. After rebooting my machine, it will auto launch the lightdm and ask login. I tried to "systemctl disable display-manager xdm". But, when I reboot the device, it will auto enable those two.
How can I disable it and just let me manually launch it?

Comment: Ubuntu, for example, has a GUI to list and disable *Startup* applications. https://www.howtogeek.com/192104/how-to-showhide-all-hidden-startup-applications-in-ubuntu-14.10/

Comment: Thank you for this information. That is for disable an app. I am not sure if it works with gui start. I will give it a try. I think I need to know how the system start and run into start the gui.